# ERROR while fecthing data from mongodb using reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

```
componentDidMount() {
       fetch('http://aws-server:3010/certificate_parser/certificate/?filter_name=Bob',{mode: 'no-cors'})
    .then(data => data.json())
       .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }));
}
```

error:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Please post error too.

Comment: Sounds like a CORS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you get an error while parsing JSON object from `data`. Your `data` probably contains incomplete JSON string, which causes and error. Try to print your data using 
`console.log(data)` to see whether it is a valid JSON string.